# Convert double to NSNumber keeping decimal part even if there are 0s

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I download some Json data that has inside it a price, the price gets downloaded as double so for example if I have 10.50 the value assigned to my variable will be 10.5, how can I keep the 0 after the first decimal number?

This is the code I used to create the NSNumber:

```
NSNumber *numPrice = jsonElement[@"Price"];  //the json is 10.50 but numPrice becomes 10.5

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundUp];

NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:numPrice];
```

Comment: have you tried [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2]; for displaying two decimal numbers

Comment: @Volker So far you have the only valid "answer". Post it as one.

Comment: Thank you @Volker this worked perfectly :) if you post it as answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For output purposes you can set your `NSNumberFormatter`to have exactly 2 decimal digits like

```
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
```

This is for displaying two decimal numbers. Internally your NSNumber will be stored of course with a single digit, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Any trailing zeros are simple a display issue, they are no part of the number.

Comment: The OP is already doing this. The comment by @Volker is the correct solution here.

Comment: Right, I should not have added the last part about formatting, deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. When a JSON document contains 10.50, it *is* the number 10.5. There is no difference between 10.5000000 or 10.50 or 10.5 in a JSON document. They are absolutely one hundred percent the same thing.

You can feel free to display this number any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the thing that you have to do if you want to show the numbers with two decimals after saving them as a NSNumber is print them as a float with two decimals. Something like that:

```
NSNumber *numPrice = jsonElement[@"Price"];  //the json is 10.50 but 

NSString *numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", numPrice.floatValue];
```